# SSL errors while installing python packages from PyPI in a databricks cluster

Tags: azure-databricks

**I am trying to install azure-storage-file-datalake in a databricks cluster, but due to internal dependency I am facing the below SSL error. I am using python 3.7.3, pip 20 and was able to install python packages that don't have any dependency or if the dependencies are already installed by default.**

java.lang.RuntimeException: ManagedLibraryInstallFailed: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Process List(/databricks/python/bin/pip, install, azure-storage-file-datalake, --disable-pip-version-check) exited with code 1. Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(104, 'ECONNRESET')"))': /simple/azure-storage-file-datalake/ Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(104, 'ECONNRESET')"))': /simple/azure-storage-file-datalake/ Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(104, 'ECONNRESET')"))': /simple/azure-storage-file-datalake/ Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(104, 'ECONNRESET')"))': /simple/azure-storage-file-datalake/ Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(104, 'ECONNRESET')"))': /simple/azure-storage-file-datalake/ Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement azure-storage-file-datalake (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for azure-storage-file-datalake for library:PythonPyPiPkgId(azure-storage-file-datalake,None,None,List()),isSharedLibrary=false

Answer (score 1):

You can try to install "`azure-storage-file-datalake`" using **Install Library** option.

**Here are the steps to install libraries using Library.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: was following the same approach but installation is failing because internally it is trying to  resolve dependencies so trying to pull that from PyPI and there it is facing SSL connect error (while connecting to PyPI may be). I tried to even download wheels and upload and install but again to resolve internal dependencies it needs to connect to PyPI and hence SSL error. (here in case of data-storage-file-datalake dependency is data-storage-blob).

Answer (score 0):

In an org level setup, have to open ports (outside of VNet) and ACL's, needs HSEC approvals.